# SonarQube IntteliJ Plugin how to run inspections on new code

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, sonarqube

We use sonarQube for creating the fency sonar reports. Since we want to see the violations in our IDE I play arround with official [Sonar Qube IntteliJ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4971?pr=). It correctly shows the violations which are already known and which it downloads from our sonar server (I guess). But new code is never analyzed. Does anybody know whether it is possible to see violations for new code before it is checked in? [Sonar Qube Community Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7238) seems to support it.

Comment: Can you share the logs of the analysis?

Comment: What do you mean with logs? I have no logs, because I do not know how to create a pre commit analyses, with the sonar qube intellij plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted on using the plugin - http://techtwaddle.net/2015/07/14/using-sonarqube-intellij-plugin-for-code-analysis/

Look at the last step in the post, you will need to set the inspection scope to 'changed files', with this only issues in new or modified files will be reported.